# Syslog server flooding network with reverse DNS lookups

Tags: linux, debian, networking, rsyslog

I have a Pi that's running a syslog server with rsyslog for my local network. The problem is when I enable it, the server spams the network with:

```
Dec  7 19:58:41 2016 SYSLOG[0]: [Host 192.168.0.1] UDP 192.168.0.52,47781 --> 8.8.8.8,53 ALLOW: Outbound access request [DNS query for 1.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.]
```

Can I stop outbound traffic from the server because it's causing the network to identify it as Lan Sidr UDP flood attack?

Answer (score 1):

To make `rsyslog` not do reverse DNS requests, edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and add:

```
global(net.enableDNS="off")
```

as described at the following link: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/compatibility/v8compatibility.html#command-line-options

and then restart the service with:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Please take note that adding -x to `RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS` in `/etc/default/rsyslog` is being deprecated, avoid it.

Comment: +1. The documentation even *warns* you that doing reverse DNS lookups on remote logs will cause a severe performance hit, and there *really is no point in doing it*. You can do the lookup easily enough when you're trying to retrieve some information, and the IP address is more pertinent than its *current* name.

Comment: I added the net.enableDNS="off", and I also tried the RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS"-x", neither one stopped the flooding.